# SQL tuning ideas

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate, oracle11g

I have a large table with a lot of columns and huge data.

The following hibernate (3.x) SQL is taking a long time in the Oracle 11g database. The slower response time is mainly due to the non-indexed columns in the where clause.

After the database analysis, it is decided as follows:

- The database table cannot be modified at this point to add index to the non-indexed columns used in the query.
- Also making the SQL part of database function/stored proceure is not an option either.
- The database tuning was already done.
- SQL has to be tuned.

How to tune/optimize the SQL to have faster response time? Would nested joins increase the response time?

Below is the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE id || '/' || name IN ( :vals )
    AND (LEAST(DECODE(dt1, 0, 999999999999, null, 999999999999, dt1)
              ,DECODE(dt2, 0,999999999999, null, 999999999999, dt2)) BETWEEN :inputVal1 AND :inputVal2
    OR ( decode(dt1, 0, null, dt1) IS NULL
        AND DECODE(dt2, 0,null, dt2) IS NULL )  )
```

Any help with examples/urls is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Would nested joins increase the response time"?  Your query has no joins.  Adding joins is not (generally) a way to improve performance.

Comment: How can you add a nested join here? This query will do the full table read every time because your conditions are based on calculations like this one: `id || '/' || name`. even having an index on ID, Name, dt1 or dt2 columns will not help here.

Comment: So what columns are indexed? If `id` and/or `name` are indexed you could possibly rewrite the query to take advantage of them. Right now it isn't. I'm a little puzzled that the database analysis outcomes that you mention.

Comment: Did you try to replace the concatenation with tuple comparison? `where (id, name) in ( (id1, name1), (id2, name2), ...)`? That might use an index on `(id, name)` if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change current tables but can you add new tables?

If your issues regards missing indexes, you can just copy the data into new tables - the price here is the duplication - and tune your SQL to use this tables instead of original. You just duplicate the data and allow SQL server to create and maintain new indexes.

The idea is to duplicate only the data contained in the indexes. The price here except duplication is probably more "joining" but according to your question, it's not problem as joining itself is the issue only when your queries perform very well.

Comment: Thank you. Our DBAs are busy, thus trying out other possible options to optimize the SQL quey itself first. Is there a way in Hibernate name query approach to use nested loop self-join? Looks like SQL hint usage is one approach but not sure if Hibernate allows in named query.